# Looking out the window of a subluminal spaceship, what would be the sight?

Tags: stars, speed-of-light

How would a star sky look for the observer flying on a subluminal spaceship (i.e., with the velocity close to the velocity of light)?

Comment: You can find numerous CGI visualizations of on YouTube if you search. Try typing "light speed visualization" into the search box.  I can't vouch for the accuracy of any of them, but at least some should be grounded in the actual theory of relativity.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you are approaching or leaving that star.  Light undergoes blue shift if the source of light is moving towards the observer (equivalently, if the observer is moving towards the source) and red shift if the observer and source are moving further apart.  The equations are not particularly simple for velocities approaching that of light, however.

Ultimately, what would happen is the star would appear to be emitting light at either a higher frequency or a lower frequency, depending on whether you were moving toward or away from it.  If you were not moving on a direct line of sight (that is, it's off to your left hand side, say, and you are going past it) then the effect would still happen and would depend on how you are moving past.

This would have the effect of making the star appear to emit light that is either more blue or red.

Comment: Blueshift/redshift is only part of the answer; there's also [Lorentz-FitzGerald contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_contraction) to consider.

Comment: Blueshift (resp. redshift) doesn't in general make the star look bluer (resp. redder), because wavelengths that were previously invisible to human eyes will be shifted into the visible spectrum to compensate. The only way to detect such a shift is to examine the spectral lines, which have no bearing on the visual appearance of the star. Frederick Pohl made such an error in his story [The Gold at the Starbow's End](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gold_at_the_Starbow%27s_End).

Comment: For most individual objects, the Lorentz-FitzGerald contraction isn't going to make much difference.  A tiny dot that appears 10 times closer is still going to look like a tiny dot.  Only objects that have an apparent size will be noticeably different.  Nearby planets will look closer and larger, but not for long, as you'll soon leave them far behind.  Distant galaxies will look larger, but once you are travelling at a constant velocity they aren't going to change much after that until you get close to them, in a few thousand years.

Comment: Might be worth noting that it's called the [(relativistic) Doppler effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect) and is quite know for [sound waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect#Sirens).